# RenderScript: One ScriptC_XXXX can't be created twice?

Tags: java, android, renderscript

This is my constructor of class RSBaseFilterEngine, and my program will create many instance of this class in different activity.

```
public RSBaseFilterEngine(Context context) {
    rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    this.context = context;
    script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
}
```

The problem is, if I get the instrance of this class more than 1 times, program will crash. The crash will occur when program is processing

```
script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
```

And, the error log is

```
Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:69)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.filter.ScriptC_BaseFilter.<init>(ScriptC_BaseFilter.java:41)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.filter.ScriptC_BaseFilter.<init>(ScriptC_BaseFilter.java:35)
at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.RSBaseFilterEngine.<init>(RSBaseFilterEngine.java:33)
```

Why ScriptC_BaseFilter can't be created twice? Then, I changed code like this

```
public RSBaseFilterEngine(Context context) {
    rs = RenderScript.create(context);
    this.context = context;
    script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
    script.destroy();
    script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
}
```

As I expected, it crashed when program invoked this constructor in the first time.

So, can anyone tell me why this hanppened? Whether there is some details I do not notice？Thanks.

---

Ok, I will post entire logcat

```
01-28 10:50:58.637: E/RenderScript(26067): Could not create symlink /data/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo/cache/com.android.renderscript.cache/librs.basefilter#93xfAC.so -> /data/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo//lib/librs.basefilter.so
01-28 10:50:58.637: E/RenderScript(26067): Unable to open shared library (/data/data/com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo//lib/librs.basefilter.so): Symbol not found: load_library[1096]: Library '/system/lib/egl/libGLESv2S3D_adreno200.so' not found
01-28 10:50:58.657: E/RenderScript(26067): Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.basefilter.so): (null)
01-28 10:50:58.657: D/AndroidRuntime(26067): Shutting down VM
01-28 10:50:58.657: W/dalvikvm(26067): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ad5228)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo/com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo.EffectActivity}: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2194)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2229)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1261)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067): Caused by: android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:69)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.filter.ScriptC_BaseFilter.<init>(ScriptC_BaseFilter.java:41)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.filter.ScriptC_BaseFilter.<init>(ScriptC_BaseFilter.java:35)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.RSBaseFilterEngine.<init>(RSBaseFilterEngine.java:64)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.RSBaseFilterEngine.getInstance(RSBaseFilterEngine.java:75)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo.EffectActivity.onCreate(EffectActivity.java:87)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4531)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2150)
01-28 10:50:58.727: E/AndroidRuntime(26067):    ... 11 more
```

---

I will post some test I made recently.

The following segments of code will make the program crash, the common point is they try to create the same script twice:

```
rs = RenderScript.create(context);
script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
rs.destroy(); // same problem occurred after changed this line to rs.finish() 
rs = RenderScript.create(context);
script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);

// create same script using different renderscript context will not help
// do rs and rs_base use the same context?
rs = RenderScript.create(context);
rs_base = RenderScript.create(context);
script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
script_base = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs_base);
```

Comment: Can you post the entire logcat, rather than just the stack trace? What device are you running this on? What SDK/Tools did you use to build the apk?

Comment: @StephenHines My device is HTC Incredible S, Android 4.0.4, CPU is Snapdragon MSM8255 with a single core, GPU is Adreno 205. I'm using version 19 to build apk.

Comment: You are running in compatibility mode on that device (since it is before the target API 18 of Android 4.3). In such a case, we attempt to create a symlink of the compatibility shared library. The peculiar thing here is that it is failing to create the symlink in the app's data directory. That is what causes the actual bug. Any ideas why your app would not really own that directory?

Comment: @StephenHines Hi, thinks for your reply. My colleague find the solution, and I post it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague find a solution to solve this problem.

First, you should make sure that these code must be added in the file "project.properties"

```
#------ RenderScript Configuration -------
renderscript.target=18

renderscript.support.mode=true

sdk.buildtools=18.1.0

#------ RenderScript Configuration -------
```

Then, replace the file "libbcc.dll" in your sdk/build-tools/18.1.0 with a bigger one (the size of the original file is less than 1M, the correct one is 5.1M).

You can download in this website
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60327&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&start=200

Answer (score 0):

Can you check with the following? rs.finish flushes all outstanding commands in renderscript

```
rs = RenderScript.create(context);
this.context = context;
script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
script.destroy();
rs.finish(); //ADD THIS LINE IN YOUR CODE 
script = new ScriptC_BaseFilter(rs);
```

Comment: Sorry, it dosen't work. The same problem occurred when processed the last line.

Comment: My temporary solution is using singleton, so this script can't be created twice.

Answer (score 0):

Is com.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.algorithms.demo the actual name of the project that you put in your .rs file pragmas? This must match exactly, or you won't be able to load the .bc/.so files.